# Breaking join in Case Of Large Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just need a common approach.

When we are joining suppose 7 table out of them 5 are huge table and 2 are small tables.

So if we execute the query in one go it will take a numerous amount of time.
So, what is the basic approach we follow to break the query.

And all the tables are having only one joining condition to the next table.

Is their any approach that can help us to optimize the joins and getting a better execution plan.

Comment: You could get the execution plan, it will a) suggest you where indexes would help perform and it will b) show you where the cost of the query is.

Comment: I already go through the execution plan.Can u help me specifically like what we need to see in the execution plan like where the nested join occur we need to break from that point or anything else.

Comment: Can you paste execution plan here.:https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: and also schema and count of the tables involved

Comment: Not sure, but you can try putting the smaller tables (tables with less records) at first and then the larger tables in the joining condition.

Comment: Added..Please verify:https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rywkXewug